# How do I turn windows features on or off using powershell or commandline in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have scripted against `sysocmgr` in Windows XP, `servermanagercmd` in server 2008, and now I find that I have to use a new PowerShell module `servermanager` to install features on Server 2008 R2 and so I would expect that I would use the same module in Windows 7 but it's not there.

How can I install Windows features using the command line or PowerShell in Windows 7?

Comment: Time has finally provided a way using powershell, my answer is below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dism.exe /online /?
```

also, check out http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Deploying-Windows-7-Part2.html

Comment: specifically [this MSDN page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx) tells you to use a command like this: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:{feature}` use `/Get-Features` to list all available features.

Comment: @EricFalsken This is now possible via powershell using the dism module.

Answer (score 6):

For a *true* powershell experience, you need to download the Windows AIK for 8.0 and use the `dism module`. It's found in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\<arch>\DISM
```

and you can just point powershell to that folder with

```
Import-Module C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\<arch>\DISM
```

Make sure you replace *< arch >* with the architecture of the machine powershell is running on. That DISM folder can even be copied and redistributed to machines if need be (speaking on functionality, I don't know if redistributing is actually *allowed* by Microsoft).

The specific command to toss out a Windows optional feature is

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -eq mediacenter
```

That will return a `Microsoft.DISM.Commands.BasicFeatureObject`, as seen [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376470(v=wps.630).aspx). From there, you can set the `state` property to disabled, like

```
$(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -eq mediacenter).state = 
    [Microsoft.DISM.Commands.FeatureState]::Disabled
```

and bye bye media center. Of course, this has to be run from an elevated prompt, and the `-Online` switch refers to the current running Windows, as opposed to an offline image.

Also, this module requires WMF 3.0 and *that* requires .NET 4.0, just FYI.

Comment: I was able to run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName NetFx3 -Online` on a Windows 8.1 machine without installing the AIK. I did, however, have the WMF5 preview installed; perhaps that provides it? The module is loaded from `C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Dism\Dism.psm1`

Answer (score 4):

Attempting to run the PowerShell from Windows 7/8 will only get you this:

> Get-WindowsFeature : The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system.

`dism` is the only way I've found that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
ocsetup.exe /?
```

In addition to dism it appears you can also use [ocsetup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766272%28WS.10%29.aspx) which is installed by default on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008. If you were looking to script something that works across all three of these then this would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Add ServerManager-feature manually. Then you can add servermanager-module:

import-module servermanager

get-windowsfeature

Comment: how would you add ServerManager feature separately?

Comment: This would work for Windows 2008R2 and newer, but not for Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

For the Powershell part, open the 'Windows Powershell Modules' prompt and enter

PS1> Add-WindowsFeature [feature name]

eg

Add-WindowsFeature SMTP-Server

Get-WindowsFeature shows you the names of all the available features

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only works on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Jeffery is correct, this does not work in windows 7 by default. If you know of a way to get it working I would like to know.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a remote session from Windows 7 to a Windows Server 2008 R2 box and run Add-WindowsFeature. I have not been able to find it on Win7 even with RSAT installed.

Comment: Wouldn't that add the feature to the Windows Server 2008 R2 box and not to the local Windows 7 instance? If not please explain.